# How to add a tooltip for just the background image of an input field with HTML and CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css, tooltip, background-image

Is there a way to show a tooltip for just the background image of an input field?

**HTML**

```
[...]
<tr>
    <td class="borderless right">
        <label class="label-required" for="Name">Name</label><span class="required">*</span>
    </td>
    <td class="borderless">
        <input 
    type="text" 
    name="myName" 
    id="myName" 
    class="text-box single-line" 
    data-val="true" 
    data-val-length="...at least n characters..." 
    data-val-length-max="50" 
    data-val-length-min="2" 
    data-val-regex="...only letters..." 
    data-val-regex-pattern="..." 
    data-val-required="...required..." />
</td>
</tr>
```

**CSS**

```
.errorImage
{
    background-image: url(...../someIcon.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right 2px top 3px;
    border: 1px solid #cc8a8a;
    background-color: #fff5f5;
}
```

The input fields are validated using jQuery validator and everything works as it should. The only minor problem is that the tooltip for invalid input fields is shown as soon as I *mouseover* the input field and not just over the icon (which is displayed at the right side within the input field).

Comment: can you provide a more complete HTML?

Comment: @AliBassam: Updated HTML although I don't think that this will be of any relevance for the question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe so.  You may have to just add a new element next to the field. and position/style accordingly based on the parent div having the error class or not.

```
<div class="name error">
    <div for="first_name" title="First name must be at least 2 characters."></div>
    <input type="text" title="First Name" placeholder="First Name *" id="first_name">
</div>
```

Comment: That's what I thought. Added the icon outside the input box as an extra element and positioned it with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Hi would say that if is the same element it will be very difficult. 
Probably the best solution is to change the generated html.
But it's probably easier if you show some html samples.